# How do I permanently change the disassembly syntax in Radare2?

Tags: radare2

As the title says, I am trying to change the default disassembly syntax in Radare2 from Intel to AT&T. Looking up documentation, I found the following.

```
[0x00405e1c]> e asm.syntax=att
```

However, changing syntax this way does not persist across sessions. Is there a command I can use to save settings permanently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `Radare2` [book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/configuration/intro.html):

> The core reads `~/.config/radare2/radare2rc` while starting. You can add
>   `e` commands to this file to tune the radare2 configuration to your
>   taste.